# Use Ember Js with java backend in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ember.js

I was given a task to do ember js as front end and Java backend in tomcat . I searched around and got some idea about frontend in ember but how to I use it with tomcat. I am completely new to this and I don't know if I have to use an API for that backend rather than using web.xml and URL pattern to match servlets. Please give some link to docs so I can refer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is purely a tomcat question. learn how to write a backend in tomcat, that you use ember frontend should not matter much.

Comment: Yes, you will need to use a backend api in Java in order to talk with Ember. Ember works like a mobile client in the sense it needs data to be sent from an api ...

Answer (score 2):

Apache Tomcat is an application server, meaning it runs the code you give it and can  listen and respond to http requests. First you have to decide how you will write the code it wil run, although you could write it all yourself it is much easier if you use a framework.

There are many types of frameworks, but the MVC model is the most popular for web backends, so learn what MVC is and how ot use it. Many frameworks can run on Tomcat, from ones written in Java all the way to Ruby on Rails (if you use JRuby, a Java implementation of the Ruby language). Rails is a great MVC framework and has all the things you will need to get the job done.

Once you have chosen a Framework you need to chose the type of API your backend will expose. Again there are many specifications to choose from but Ember uses [JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/). You will need to find a library that works with your chosen framework that turns Java objects into JSON:API. Rails has many of these libraries, but I would recommend the jsonapi-resources because it will autogenerate a lot of the code you will need.

It is a lot of work, but here are some things you will need to know to get the job done:

[What is MVC](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really)

[Getting started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

[Using Rails on Tomcat](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jruby-to-run-a-rails-application-on-apache-tomcat-7-and-ubuntu-14-04)

[What is JSON:API](http://jsonapi.org/)

[A JSON:API library for rails](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources)

Having said all of that StackOverflow is not really a place to ask for recommendations on books, tools, software librarys, tutorials or other off-site resources since that usually leads to people arguing and links usually break. I guess that is the reason your question got downvoted. Keep this in mind for your next question :)

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation

Answer (score 0):

If it helps:
Currently we are using java backend (Jersey) with emberjs frontend, and the communication runs between APIs.

You can find some instructions on [Jersey's github](https://jersey.github.io/), Ember js will be the static webpage on Tomcat, Jersey can be the backend which can create some awesome apis for you.